# Struts 2 not calling action class execute() method

Tags: java, struts2

i am new to Struts2 and created a simple HelloWorld app in struts but the issue is my action class is not being called when i click the submit button, there is not any exception on the console as well.
here is my code,

**`web.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**`struts.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
        value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <action name="helloAction"
            class="com.tutorial.struts2.HelloWorldAction">
            <result name="success">helloworld.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**`index.jsp`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Struts</h1>
     <form action="/helloAction">
      <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="userName"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
   </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**`HelloWorldAction`**

```
package com.tutorial.struts2;


public class HelloWorldAction {

    public String userName;

    public String execute() throws Exception{
        System.out.println(userName);
        return "success";
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

**`helloworld.jsp`**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
     Hello World, <s:property value="userName"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**helloworld.jsp**

```
<s:property value="name"/>
```

where is `name` property?? in which action class you have declared `name` property?

It should be  `<s:property value="userName"/>`

remember struts will try to find out the getter method of your property file by putting the `get+YourProperty()`

In your case it will, try to find out `getName()` method inside your action class which is not available.

**Edited:**

Your url for `helloAction` is not mapped correctly
try to run this in your browser,

```
http://yourIp:port/yourApplicationName/yourNameSpace/yourAction
```

which will become for your project as

```
http://yourIp:8080/HelloWorldStruts/testNameSp/helloAction
```

Comment: You are 100% right my friend but this time my issue is the action class that is not getting called, issue you are tell will produce after action class call, but my app is not invoking the execute()

Comment: see your URL on the browser how it is? is it correct mapped with your action?

Comment: This is URL IP:8080/helloAction?userName=testString ... where helloAction is my action name... please share if any thing wrong

Comment: **Suggestion:** try to run Ip:`8080/helloAction` only

Comment: execute will run bydefualt, if not try to add method name also.

Comment: yes it will be called by default but if call will go to that action, but can not call the action class... can't understand why ..?

Answer (score 2):

i think you need to make two changes in  the code

```
public class HelloWorldAction extends Action
```

is the 1st one and 2nd, user struts property for form to post action

```
<s:form action="helloAction">
```

Hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you should extend `Action` in your action class:

```
public class HelloWorldAction extends Action {
```

Comment: `import org.apache.struts.action.Action;`

Comment: @RussellGutierrez, not necessary to extends Action class to implement a Hello World application in struts2

Answer (score 0):

Try by extending `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport` class and override execute method like this

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class HelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport{

    public String execute() {
        System.out.println(userName);
        return "success";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

beware: **it is for Struts 1**

I had the same problem, but I've solved mine by removing `forward` property in `action-mappings`

This one is correct:

```
<action-mappings>
    <action input="/user_list.jsp" name="UserAddFormBean" path="/userAdd" 
            scope="request" 
            type="com.minetronics.struts.UserAdd" validate="true" forward="/user_add.jsp">
            <forward name="success" path="/user_add.jsp"/>
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

But this is going to skip calling `execute` and will go straight to `forward`

```
<action-mappings>
    <action input="/user_list.jsp" name="UserAddFormBean" path="/userAdd" 
            scope="request" 
            type="com.minetronics.struts.UserAdd" validate="true">
            <forward name="success" path="/user_add.jsp"/>
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

Comment: The question is about S2, your answer is S1.